# Python Rope: How to Find all missing imports and errors in all sub modules refactoring

Tags: python, refactoring, automated-tests

I am trying to find all missing import statements and errors for each module and its sub modules.

Is there a dedicated tool for what I am trying to do?

The code that I wrote, but seems really terrible and maybe something like this exists already?:

```
import os
def find_missing_imports(walk):
    for items in walk:
        d = items[0]
        f_list = items[1]
        for f in f_list:
            module = f[:-3]
            # posix_path
            module_path = d.lstrip('.').replace('/','.').lstrip('.')
            try:
                __import__(module_path, fromlist=[module])
            except IndentationError, e:
                #print(f,e)
                pass
            except NameError, e:
                print(d,f,e)
                pass
            except Exception, e:
                print(f,e)
                pass

walk = [[root,files] for root,dirs,files in os.walk('.') for fn in files if  fn.endswith('.py')]
find_missing_imports(walk)
```

Outputs:

```
.[snip]
('./Sky_Group_Inventory_Scanner-wxpython/display_image/Dialogs', 'ImageSelectionFrame.py', NameError("name 'wx' is not defined",))
('./Sky_Group_Inventory_Scanner-wxpython/display_image/Dialogs', 'ItemSpecificsDialog.py', NameError("name 'wx' is not defined",))
('./Sky_Group_Inventory_Scanner-wxpython/display_image/Dialogs', 'ReturnCorrectWatchTitle.py', NameError("name 'wx' is not defined",))
.[snip]
```

My project before refactoring was a mess but sort of useful, now its broken after refactoring.

After reading 'The Pragmatic Programmer' based on suggestions from my initial post on codereview:

- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/46223/wxpython-item-information-scraper

I have been digging around in the source code of:

`/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rope`

Documentation for ROPE seems a little sparse. I have also been using Ninja-IDE, but haven't been able to find a solution for the problem that I am facing.

Overall I think I missed the boat on what refactoring is all about.

The current parent directory layout can be seen [here.](https://github.com/jmunsch/Sky_Group_Inventory_Scanner-wxpython/tree/5-13-14_1-refactoring)

[image]

In comparison to what it was [before.](https://github.com/jmunsch/Sky_Group_Inventory_Scanner-wxpython/tree/5-7-14_1)

[image: before]

Any help, on filling in missing terminology, or on what I am even asking would be great.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`pip install pylint`

Point pylint to the folder/module in question:

`pylint /path/to/module > pylint_output`

Where `/path/to/module` is the location of the python module you're interested in looking at.

For example:

```
my_project
   |____  moduleA
             |____  __init__.py
             |____  A.py
   |____  moduleB
             |____  __init__.py
             |____  B.py
```

- `./my_project/moduleA`
- `./my_project/moduleB`

This will create a file with Global Evaluations on:

- **undefined-variable** <-- This is what I was looking for in each file.
- invalid-name
- line-too-long
- superfluous-parens
- bad-whitespace
- attribute-defined-outside-init
- missing-docstring
- bad-indentation
- bad-continuation
- broad-except
- unused-argument
- unused-import
- unused-variable
- no-self-use
- no-member
- fixme
- unnecessary-pass
- multiple-statements
- too-many-statements
- duplicate-code
- too-many-locals
- missing-final-newline
- too-many-instance-attributes
- too-many-branches
- redefined-builtin
- too-many-public-methods
- syntax-error
- relative-import
- maybe-no-member
- import-error
- super-on-old-class
- bare-except
- undefined-loop-variable
- too-many-return-statements
- too-many-arguments
- too-few-public-methods
- star-args
- reimported
- indexing-exception
- unreachable
- too-many-lines
- redefined-outer-name
- property-on-old-class
- pointless-string-statement
- pointless-statement
- old-style-class
- no-name-in-module
- global-variable-undefined
- expression-not-assigned
- bad-except-order
- assignment-from-none

Of interest and the direct answer to my question is that within the pylint results there will be lines that have this sort of layout:

```
************* Module module_name.sub_module.class_name.method_name
R: line_no, column: Issue description 'some_name' (issue-type)
C: line_no, column: Issue description 'some_name' (issue-type)
W: line_no, column: Issue description 'some_name' (issue-type)
E: line_no, column: Issue description 'some_name' (issue-type)
F: line_no, column: Issue description 'some_name' (issue-type)
************* Module module_name.sub_module.class_name.method_name
R: line_no, column: Issue description 'some_name' (issue-type)
C: line_no, column: Issue description 'some_name' (issue-type)
W: line_no, column: Issue description 'some_name' (issue-type)
E: line_no, column: Issue description 'some_name' (issue-type)
F: line_no, column: Issue description 'some_name' (issue-type)
```

- [R]efactor for a “good practice” metric violation
- [C]onvention for coding standard violation
- [W]arning for stylistic problems, or minor programming issues
- [E]rror for important programming issues (i.e. most probably bug)
- [F]atal for errors which prevented further processing

So an issue-type of (undefined-variable) in most of my cases indicate modules that have not been imported. `pylint -E /path/to/module` will return only the undefined-variable errors.

Comment: Where is `/path/to/module` located?

Comment: @alper it would be the python module you'd like to check. I'll update my answer. Let me know if this answer is still valid.

Comment: Yes sir its valid. I just confused that I have to use node-mode to make `pylint` work.